# missing return statement without throw new IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, illegalargumentexception

I am looking at the leetcode two sum code and am confused about throw new IllegalArgumentException statement. The goal of the code is to return indices of the two numbers such that they add up to a specific target, given an array of integers. It is assumed that each input would have exactly one solution, and you may not use the same element twice. Here is the code:

if I run this code without the throw `new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution")`, it shows error message:

> Line 10: error: missing return statement
>       }
>       ^

But if I add throw `new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution")`, the code runs smoothly.

My question is that, since ***it is assumed that there is exactly one solution to each input, why does the throw new IllegalArgumentException matter in this case.*** Thanks.

```
class Solution {
    public int[] twoSum(int[] nums, int target) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
            for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
                if (nums[i] + nums [j] == target) {
                    return new int[] {i, j};
                }
            }
        }
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("No two sum solution");
    }
}
```

Comment: Your assumption does not help the compiler. It requires a valid return on all possible pathes.

Comment: Thanks Andy for the detailed explanation. That clarified everything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler has no way to know your assumption about there being exactly one solution.

The rules around reachability of statements are actually quite basic. In particular, because the loop guard on the outer loop is present and not a constant expression with value `true`, the compiler considers that the loop body might never be executed. As such, you need to handle that eventuality.

Because the method is non-void, you have to either return a value or throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to SO!

The compiler will analyze your code and needs to terminate each path through your code that can be reached, with a proper exit statement.

Since you declared to return an integer array, each path must lead to an end where a return statement returns that declared type.

Since you can only reach the return inside your if inside your for inside your for, the compiler can easily find a way around it:

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {
```

will not be entered if `num.length == 0`. Since you do not check this, even a smart compiler must expect an empty array as valid input (even a null is valid - and will crash your function)

```
for (int j = i + 1; j < nums.length; j++) {
```

again, requires `num.length > j`. Since `num.length==1` is a valid input, you will not enter this for loop.

```
if (nums[i] + nums [j] == target) {
```

The last hurdle to your return statement is completely dependent to your array's content and the value of `target`. As these values are only known at runtime and the compiler is a little bit mimimi about things it doesn't know beforehand, it will expect you to provide many input that will fail this condition, so the return is never reached.

So, the compiler can easily see, that there are code-paths that have no proper return statement. Throwing the exception is an alternative terminating statement and thus makes your compiler happy.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation. That solved the problem.